# Force page break after so many lines?

Tags: html, css

we're using Coldfusion and SQL and are trying to make a page with a query with only one tablr with one row and need it to force a page break after so many rows. We could also have it force a page break after 8x11 page is filled. I'm using a header and it will never show the header on page 2 sense it can't figure out where the page break is. Any help would be great.

Thanks

```
<head>
<script>
thead {
position: sticky;
top: 0px;
}
</script>
</head>
<thead>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0"     align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" contenteditable="false">
<td bgcolor="#EDE9C6" width="5px"> 
  <div align="center"><nobr><font size="-2">fmt</font></div> 
</td>
<td style="overflow:hidden;" bgcolor="#EDE9C6" width="23px"> 
  <div align="center"><strong><font size="-2">    <nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;category&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    </font></strong></div>
</td>
<td bgcolor="EDE9C6" width="20px"> 
  <div align="center"><nobr><font size="-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SKU&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></div> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="EDE9C6" width="25px"> 
  <div align="center"><strong><nobr><font size="-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;artist&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></strong></div> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="EDE9C6" width="25px"> 
  <div align="center"><nobr> <font size="-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;title&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></div> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="EDE9C6" width="5px"> 
  <div align="center"><strong><nobr><font size="-2"><strong>qs&nbsp;    </strong></font></strong></div> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="EDE9C6" width="12px"> 
  <div align="center"><nobr><font size="-2">fa&nbsp;</font></div></td>
<td bgcolor="EDE9C6" width="12px"> 
  <div align="center"><strong><font size="-2"><strong>ts&nbsp;</strong>    </font></strong></div> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="EDE9C6" width="12px"> 
  <div align="center"><nobr><font size="-2">wtd&nbsp;</font></div> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="EDE9C6" width="12px"><div align="center"><strong><font size="-2">mtd&nbsp;</font></strong></div></td>
<td bgcolor="EDE9C6" width="12px"><div align="center"><font size="-2">ytd&nbsp;</font></div></td>
<td bgcolor="EDE9C6" width="20px"> 
  <div align="center"><font size="-2"><strong>price</strong></font>
    </div></td>

<td bgcolor="EDE9C6" width="15px"> 
  <div align="center"><font size="-2">check</font>
  </div></td>

</table></thead>

<table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" contenteditable="false">
<tbody>
<cfoutput query="myquery">
<tr> 
<td bgcolor="ffffff" width="5px"> 
  <div align="center"><nobr><font size="-2">#fmt#</font></div> 
</td>
<td style="overflow:hidden;" bgcolor="ffffff" width="50px"> 
  <div align="center"><strong><nobr><font size="-2">#Left(catdesc,20)#    </font></strong></div>
</td>
<td bgcolor="ffffff" width="20px"> 
  <div align="center"><nobr><font size="-2">#fsku#</font></div> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="ffffff" width="25px"> 
  <div align="center"><strong><nobr><font size="-2">#Left(artist,25)#    </font></strong></div> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="ffffff" width="25px"> 
  <div align="center"><nobr><em><font size="-2">#Left(title,25)#</font>    </em></div> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="ffffff" width="8px"> 
  <div align="center"><strong><nobr><font size="-2">#fUpStkQty#</font>    </strong></div> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="ffffff" width="12px"> 
  <div align="center"><nobr><font size="-2"><cfif #Fas# is not "">X<cfelseif #Fas# is "">&nbsp;&nbsp;</cfif></font></div></td>
<td bgcolor="ffffff" width="12px"> 
  <div align="center"><strong><font size="-2">#fStockQty#</font></strong>    </div> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="ffffff" width="12px"> 
  <div align="center"><nobr><font size="-2">#fNSWTD1#</font></div> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="ffffff" width="12px"><div align="center"><strong><font size="-2">#fNSMTD1#</font></strong></div></td>
<td bgcolor="ffffff" width="12px"><div align="center"><font size="-2">#fNSYTD1#</font></div></td>
<td bgcolor="ffffff" width="20px"> 
  <div align="center"><strong><font size="-2">$#fcost#</font></strong>
    </div></td>

<td bgcolor="ffffff" width="15px"> 
  <div align="center"><font size="-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
  </div></td>

 </cfoutput></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: _"... tablr with one row and need it to force a page break after so many rows."_ So is it 1 row or many rows? In your markup I only see 1 `<tr>` with no closing tag and your `<thead>` is not inside the table. Make sure you have valid HTML markup. It should be `<table>` -> `<tbody>` -> `<tr>` -> `<td>`

Comment: Sorry didn't state on what the query returns. It's many rows varying in how many. It's usually a couple of pages.